# Rails 3, app/lib not loaded with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a controller "A" which requires a file in a subdirectory of app/lib (ex: app/lib/a_folder/my_class.rb).

So I did something like this :

```
require 'a_folder/my_class'

class AController < ApplicationController
  # Some stuff using MyClass
end
```

It works well when I use the application, but doesn't work when I launch RSpec.

This is how my RSpec file looks:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'lib/import_functions' # Rails.root/spec/lib/import_functions.rb

RSpec.describe AController, type: controller do
  # My tests routines
end
```

When I start rspec it tells me the require in the controller file doesn't found the file (`require': cannot load such file), while it works well when I start the app.

I've added a puts $LOAD_PATH just before the require and it appears that Rails.root/app/lib is not present.

I use Rails 3.2 and rspec-rails 3.2.

Does anyone have any idea why it happens and how to fix it please ?

Thank you for your future answers.

Answer (score 2):

lib files are not auto loaded. You can put the following configuration in your application.rb, it has a problem also it will load all files under lib directory.

```
config.autoload_paths += "#{Rails.root}/lib/"
```

Or you can load your lib files in your RSpec as following code

```
require_relative "../../lib/a_folder/my_class.rb"
```

or

```
require 'lib/a_folder/my_class.rb'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already added lib into the load path long time ago. Actually I just figured out the problem was not in the code (since I did add spec the same way I always do it was weird it didn't work), but in the filename ... My spec file was called foobar.spec.rb instead of foobar_spec.rb ...